# How to get file path or binary content of file in sap.m.UploadCollection

Tags: sapui5

I want to retrieve the binary content of a file I upload with the UploadCollection control. If I were able to get the full path of the file, there would be a way to do it with a file reader, but I can't seem to find it.

Is there another way I can get the file location or the binary content?

```
<UploadCollection id="idUploader" maximumFilenameLength="55" maximumFileSize="10" multiple="true" sameFilenameAllowed="false"
                instantUpload="true" noDataDescription="Drop files or use the &quot;+&quot; button for pending upload" change="onChange"
                fileDeleted="onFileDeleted" filenameLengthExceed="onFilenameLengthExceed" fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed" typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch"
                uploadComplete="onUploadComplete" beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts" class="sapUiLargeMarginStart sapUiTinyMarginTop uploader"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this with the onChange event of sap.m.UploadCollection.

```
    onChange: function(oEvent) {
        var that = this;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var file = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var raw = e.target.result;
            sap.m.MessageToast.show("binary string: " + raw);
        };

        reader.onerror = function(e) {
            sap.m.MessageToast.show("error");
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    },
```